# Do Scala files need to be released before deleting?

Tags: scala

In the code below, if I uncomment the for loop the file no longer gets deleted

```
val file = "myfile.csv"
//for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines()) { }
new File(file).delete()
```

If so is there some type of close function that I should be calling?

Comment: Windows locks files when they're opened, preventing other actions like deletion. You're correct, you do need to explicitly close the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some sort of close that you should be calling:

```
val file = "myfile.csv"
val source = Source.fromFile(file)
for (line <- source.getLines()) { }
source.close
new File(file).delete
```

but this is a bit tedious.  If you rewrite the for loop as

```
source.getLines().foreach{ line => }
```

you can then

```
class CloseAfter[A <: { def close(): Unit }](a: A) {
  def closed[B](f: A => B) = try { f(a) } finally { a.close }
}
implicit def close_things[A <: { def close(): Unit }](a: A) = new CloseAfter(a)
```

and now your code would become

```
val file = "myfile.csv"
Source.fromFile(file).closed(_.foreach{ line => })
new File(file).delete
```

(which would be a benefit if you're doing it many times in your code, or if you already maintain your own library of helpful functions and it would be easy to add the closing implicit just once there so you could use it everywhere).

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, yes, you need to close the `Source` when you're done with it.  Another good solution is to use [scala-arm](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm) to automagically close the file for you.

```
import resource._

val file = "myfile.csv"
for {
  source <- managed(Source.fromFile(file))
  line <- source.getLines()
} {
}
new File(file).delete
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading "[Why doesn't Scala Source `close` the underlying `InputStream`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762843/why-doesnt-scala-source-close-the-underlying-inputstream)", use instead "[**scala-incubator / scala-io**](https://github.com/scala-incubator/scala-io)".

It includes a [delete operation](http://jesseeichar.github.com/scala-io-doc/0.3.0-SNAPSHOT/index.html#!/file/delete) on [a `Path`](https://github.com/scala-incubator/scala-io/blob/master/file/src/main/scala/scalax/file/Path.scala) which takes care of everything. That library always always ensures that files are safely closed after each use.